# Select2 go to href link

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 js library but I can't not put the links into the select options. 
Here is my json structure

```
[{id: 1, title: "Foo", slug: "foo"}]
```

And my select2 script

```
$(".search-box").select2({
    placeholder: "Enter...",
    ajax: {
        url: window.location.href + '/search',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term // search term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.title,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    maximumSelectionLength: 6
});
```

What I expect is when i type and click the title of SELECT OPTION i want the browser go to the post's address (link)

So any help plzzz

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `window.location.href` in the URL. Instead, use proper page URL path.

`window.location.href` is mainly use for page redirection.

Comment: But... i used it and it worked fine, and the problem isn't on line "url: window.location.href + '/search',"